# Display bootstrap pop up without defining the HTML (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to display a bootstrap pop up on the website, without predefining the HTML of it on html.

An alternative would be to define it in Javascript or separate html template.

Can you explain me how I can achieve it?

Comment: `createElement`, `appendChild`, `insertAdjacentHTML`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the HTML node using Javscript and then open bootstrap modal.

```
var modalHTML = '<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"> \
                 <div class="modal-header">\
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>\
                <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                </div>\
               <div class="modal-footer">\
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>\
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>\
                </div>\
              </div>';
 $('.container').append( modalHTML);
 $("#myModal1").modal()
```

[DEMO JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1570/)